# xclip to multiple targets

Tags: clipboard, xclip

How do I copy different texts to multiple targets using xclip (or other tools)?

I tried doing

```
echo "TEST_STRING" | xclip -selection clipboard -t STRING 
echo "TEST_HTML" | xclip -selection clipboard -t text/html
```

but the second command resets the target STRING.

Comment: I think this is beyond the capabilities of simple tools like xclip. If Python is an option, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902263/how-can-python-access-the-x11-clipboard might help.